# React 'match' of undefined on pass a params

Tags: javascript, reactjs

someone could spare a hint on this?
in this exemple after get the comments with this function

```
 getComments() {
        fetch("/posts/" + this.props.match.params.id + "/comments", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",

            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })

            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
```

load function

```
 load() {
        return this.props.getComments().then(comments => {
            this.setState({ comments });

            return comments;
        });
    }
```

**in the react log shows:**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

poiting to:

[image]

as in this case even the undefined that the log refers i have no idea which undefined the logs talks about.
please someone could clarify why react is complaining about undefined?

console.log  result of getComments

[image]

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is inside `getComments()`

Comment: @MattWay, thank you for your interest. but what?

Comment: @MattWay sorry, but i have any idea what you said

Comment: @lula please put all of component code involved in Your issue

Comment: @num8er ok, just a moment

Comment: looks like you didn't bind `getComments` so it doesn't have access to `this.props`

Comment: @lula, add `console.log(this)` as the first line inside the `getComments()` function. What is logged?

Comment: @MattWay i'll post the screenshot

Comment: make sure you bind the methods in the constructor so that it references the proper `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your function like this:

```
return this.props.getComments().then(comments => {
```

What this means is that inside your `getComments` function, `this` will reference the props object, and not your component. So when you call `this.props.match`, you are getting `undefined` because `this` is already a reference of the props. In other words, it is the same as you calling

```
`this.props.props.match`
```

from inside your render function. Obviously that will give you undefined because `props.props` does not exist.

In order to fix this, the simplest way is to just access `match` directly from `this`. Eg. `this.match.params` as `this` is already your props object. The problem though by your screenshot is that the props object doesn't actually have a match key on it (you'll have to figure out why).

The better solution though, is to pass your match details to the `getComments()` function, as it looks like it serves a very specific purpose. For example:

```
function getComments(id) {
  fetch(`/posts/${id}/comments`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
...
```